# Using a mocked module in vitest

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, vitest

I'm writing a utility that leverages an imported module and I'm a bit confused on how to properly mock it.

In the implementation I'll need to call the various methods around the imported module like this;

```
map = leaflet
    .map('map')
    .setView([38.58, -90.28], 15);
```

So it seems that I'll need two levels of mocks: mocking the `map` function and then mocking the object it returns that has the `setView` method on it.

In my test suite I have a beforeEach lifecycle hook that tries to mock the module:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    vi.mock("leaflet", () => { // Mock the import itself

        // mocking the `Map` object returned from the `map()` function call
        vi.mock("leaflet.Map", () => { 
            return {setView: vi.fn()}
        })

        // mocking the `map()` function and returning the mocked `Map` instance(?)
        const mapMock = vi.fn()
            .mockImplementation((id) => {
                return new Map("")
            })

        // returning the object to replace the whole module import with
        return {
            default: {
                map: () => mapMock,
            }
        }
    })
})
```

But when I use this in my test:

```
it("can attach a map to the dom", () => {
    const config = new MapConfiguration(
        "map",
        new GeographicCoordinates(38.0, -90.0),
        15,
        19
    )

    attachMap(config)

    expect(leaflet.map).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

I get a weird error and I'm not sure what it's trying to tell me

[image]
I've no doubt that I'm misunderstanding the documentation as far as how to mock the module, but I'm not sure which part or parts I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please, provide the error as text, some info is truncated and is relevant for indexing. I'm not sure what's the point of `vi.mock("leaflet.Map",`

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that `vi.mock()` is mocking an entire module, so calling `vi.mock("leaflet.Map")` doesn't really work. The [path parameter of `vi.mock()`](https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-mock) refers to the module being imported, so to mock the "leaflet" module you need to `vi.mock("leaflet")` and then mock return values of those functions appropriately. Additionally, calling it inside of another mock won't work. And they will both get hoisted to the top of the file anyways, so putting it inside of a `beforeEach` won't do anything.

To mock leaflet, at the most basic level, something like the following would work:

```
import leaflet from "leaflet";
import { expect, it, vi } from "vitest";

vi.mock("leaflet", () => {
  return {
    default: {
      map: vi.fn().mockReturnValue({
        setView: vi.fn(),
      }),
    },
  };
});

it("can attach a map to the dom", () => {
  const config = new MapConfiguration(
    "map",
    new GeographicCoordinates(38.0, -90.0),
    15,
    19,
  );

  attachMap(config);

  expect(leaflet.map).toHaveBeenCalledWith("map");
});
```

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz Did this explain what you were seeing? Did you find another solution?

Comment: Looking at this again, I should probably note that the mock syntax given here is dependent on the manner in which `leaflet` is imported (both in the test and source). When I wrote the answer, I must have been using the default import of leaflet to test it with. It seemed to have worked, but if it is instead imported using a namespace import (`import * as leaflet from "leaflet"`, which might also work, depending on the bundler used), then the mock would have to be adjusted to match.